# React Native 5.x: Find my own bluetooth mac address

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, mac-address

It's possible to get my own Bluetooth mac address using react-native 5.x?
I tried many packages but the result is the same, I manage to see other mac addresses but not mine. On my android phone, I can see the mac address from settings -> About phone -> status -> Bluetooth address. If someone can put me on the track. I've already used:

- [react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info)
- [react-native-bluetooth-serial-next](https://github.com/nuttawutmalee/react-native-bluetooth-serial-next)

Comment: hi pro,
what did you do for this issues

Comment: I made it using android.

Comment: how i tried to make one but i can't with native module 

did you get local bluetooth mac address ?